# Proof by induction : Sequences, and inequalities. How do I prove both sides of the inequality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

[image: Only shown the step of how Pk implies Pk+1.]

$$
u_{n+1} = \frac{u^{2}_{n}+4}{u_{n}+2}
$$

I can prove that $u_{k+1}$ must be less than 2, but how do I show that it is greater than 0?

Comment: Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to *type* mathematics here instead of relying on what appears to be an attempt at drawing the text using mspaint.

Comment: $u_1=1 > 0$. If $u_n > 0$ what about $u_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: It's funny you could prove the "harder" part, but got stuck in essentially a trivial part: by induction, as $u_i>0$ , we have $u_{i+1}>0$ by using the formula for $u_{i+1}$.

Comment: Indeed, supposing $u_n$ is positive, we have $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n^2+4}{u_n+2}=\frac{\text{something positive}}{\text{something else positive}}$ which is again positive.  If that is unsatisfying, then go back even further and using field axioms for the real numbers prove that a positive number times a positive number is positive and that the multiplicative inverse of a positive number is positive.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align*}
0 < u_{n+1} < 2 & \iff 0 < \frac{u_n^2 + 4}{u_n + 2} < 2 \\
& \iff 0 < u_n^2 + 4 < 2 \cdot (u_n + 2) \\
& \iff 0 < u_n^2 + 4 < 2 u_n + 4 \\
& \iff 0 < u_n^2 < 2 u_n \\
& \iff 0 < u_n < 2
\end{align*}
$$

and the last line holds true by our induction hypothesis. Q.E.D.

Comment: Actually you have already used the induction hypothesis when you multiplied the inequalities with $u_n+2$ and divided by $u_n$ ... had these been negative, the inequality would have reversed.  Apart from that, the answer is fine.

Comment: @Macavity I was fully aware of that but thought it would be obvious to the reader ;-)